# use Google Sheets QUERY to sum column weeknum = weeknum on a different sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

I have a spreadsheet with 2 sheets in it, I want to summarize the weekly results by date. I'm trying to use the query sum function to summarize everything since I wasn't able to do it with arrayformula.

but I'm not able to do it with a query as well. I don't want to just copy-paste the sum function from each row to the next I want to just type the date I need in column A and get all the results in the different columns.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZsKXw32ycO_5KGD2I-Ug_GmqSIB_Z-D3Z1jlGd6fpTE/edit?usp=sharing

link to sheets.

getting the data from the database sheet. I want to display the data-oriented by date and summed.

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(FILTER(QUERY(DataBase!A2:E,"select A,sum(E) 
  where A is not null
  group by A
  label sum(E)''"), WEEKNUM(DataBase!A2:A)=WEEKNUM(A2:A))
))
```

I tried this formula and it dosent work..

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 QUERY(FILTER(DataBase!A2:E,WEEKNUM(DataBase!A2:A)=WEEKNUM(A2)),
 "select Col1,sum(Col5) 
  where Col1 is not null
  group by Col1
  label sum(Col5)''"), 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: () It dosent work, it only shows the same day results, and not the weekly results.. it spoused to show more then 204, since in the next day there were more data added.